# CSS max() width in column table

Tags: html, css

I have a sliding table. For a certain column I try to use

```
width: max(33.33%, 200px)
```

But it doesn't work. I found the note [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max()):

> Math expressions involving percentages for widths and heights on table columns, table column groups, table rows, table row groups, and table cells in both auto and fixed layout tables may be treated as if auto had been specified

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe the `min-width` workaround could be helpful with `min-width: 33.33%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `min-width` works:

```css
td:first-child {
  width:33.3%;
  min-width:150px;  
}
td {
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="resize:both; overflow:auto; padding:2em; background:#fec">
  <table style="border:1px solid red; width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
      <td>cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I use vuetify v-data-table and min-width doesn't work

Comment: I just tested it and it seams to work..!? https://codepen.io/tobias_buschor/pen/abWyKXE

Comment: I set min-width: 500px to the first column and it doesn't work. You can reduce the width of the first column to less than 500px

Comment: Hm i tested in firefox and chrome, added a screenshot, can you check?